# Executando operações distintas de acordo com o preenchimento de parametros opcionais SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where

bom dia!
Estou desenvolvendo uma proc onde preciso verificar se meus parâmetros opcionais estão preenchidos ou não, se estiverem executar um tipo de where se não estiverem executar outro.

Atualmente meu where está dessa forma:

WHERE

EXISTS(

SELECT 1

FROM Tabela2 WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE
( Tabela2.id                       = Tabela1.id )
AND ( YEAR(Tabela2.Data)               = YEAR(Tabela1.Data) )
AND ( MONTH(Tabela2.Data)              = MONTH(Tabela1.Data ) )
AND ( Tabela2.sinc = 'A' )
AND Tabela1.stac IN ('I', 'R')
)

OR
(
@dataInicial        IS NOT NULL
AND @dataFinal          IS NOT NULL
AND @id                 IS NOT NULL
AND @id                 = Tabela1.id
AND(Tabela1.Data)       BETWEEN @dataInicial AND @dataFinal
)

Preciso verificar se meus parametros @idEmpresa,@dataInicial e @dataFinal foram preenchidos e puxar as informações de acordo com os parametros, caso contrário executar a operação "exists"

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

Experimente colocar os filtros na ordem que você disse, primeiro os filtros pelo ID e data, e depois o Exists.
Nos filtros por ID e data não é necessário verificar se os parâmetros são nulos, pois se forem a condição será falsa, e quando as condições forem verdadeiras o Exists não deverá ser executado porque está sendo utilizado o OR antes dele e os mecanismos dos bancos de dados conseguem otimizar a execução.

```
WHERE

(
    Tabela1.id = @id AND
    Tabela1.Data BETWEEN @dataInicial AND @dataFinal
)

or

EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Tabela2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        Tabela2.id = Tabela1.id AND
        YEAR(Tabela2.Data) = YEAR(Tabela1.Data) AND
        MONTH(Tabela2.Data) = MONTH(Tabela1.Data AND 
        Tabela2.sinc = 'A' AND 
        Tabela1.stac IN ('I', 'R') 
)
```

Espero que ajude